# Change the text after set the timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with change the text while I set up the timer. When I click on a button, it will disable the button and it will change the text while I start the timer for 3 seconds, then enable it and change the text back to where it was.

When I try this:

```
<button name="btn1" id="btn1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-size">Click Here!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "<span><i class=\'fa fa-spinner fa-spin\'></i> Loading</span>";

    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = false;
    }, 3000);

    if(document.getElementById("btn1").disabled == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "Click Here again!";
    }

});
</script>
```

It wont let me to change the text back to where it was as I still getting `Loading` with fa-spin icon after the timer ended in 3 seconds.

I have also tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckTimer(){
    document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "<span><i class=\'fa fa-spinner fa-spin\'></i> Loading</span>";

    document.getElementById("btn1").value="Please wait";
    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = false;
    }, 3000);

    if(document.getElementById("btn1").disabled == false)
    {
        document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = "Click Here!";
    }

}
</script>
```

I still get the same problem. I have try to find the answer but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Can you please show me an example how I can change the text back to where it was after when I click on a button to start the timer for 3 seconds that disable the button and change the text until when the timer end so I can change the text back to where it was?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the text of the button in the callback of the timeout. Here's a pure javascript implementation:

```
<button
  name="btn1"
  id="btn1"
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-size"
>
  Click Here!
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const btn = document.getElementById("btn1");
  btn.onclick = function(e) {
    btn.innerHTML =
      "<span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Loading</span>";
    btn.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      btn.disabled = false;
      btn.innerText = "Click here again!";
    }, 3000);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change back the text **into** the setTimeout callback :

**Pure Vanilla JS (EDIT)**

```js
const b = document.getElementById('b');

b.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let prev = b.innerHTML;  
  b.innerHTML = 'Wait';
  b.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    b.disabled = false;
    b.innerHTML = prev;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<button id="b">Click</button>
```

**Pure JQuery**

```js
$('#b').click(function() {
  let prev = $('#b').html();  
  $('#b').html('wait');
  $('#b').prop('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#b').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#b').html(prev);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b">Click</button>
```